# JQuery Add class to certain list item

Tags: jquery, list

I am trying to add a script that will add a class to a list item that I choose..

I have tried this but it didnt add the class

```
$('.navigation ul li').get(0).addClass("active");
```

What Am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.eq()`

```
$('.navigation ul li').eq(0).addClass("active");
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

---

Why `get()` didn't worked ? see this -
[jQuery : eq() vs get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709660/jquery-eq-vs-get)

Answer (score 2):

use `.children().eq()`

```
$('.navigation ul').children().eq(0).addClass('class');
```